# Creating variable number of views

Tags: android, variables, view

I have been working on creating a variable number of my custom views and i have not been able to create anything that doesn't lead to the app force stopping. I have looked at a couple different resources but have not been able to find any help. Sorry if this is obvious i am somewhat new at this.

my main activity code

```
package com.example.customview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.example.customview.widget.DoubleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        DoubleImageView doubleimageview;
        for (int i =0; i <5; i++) {
            doubleimageview = new DoubleImageView(this);
            linearlayout.addView(doubleimageview);
        }
    }
}
```

my Double_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.example.customview.widget.DoubleImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_us"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/flag_uk"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:text="@string/score"
                android:spacing="15dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

To me this should work to add double_image views to a scrollable linear layout i'm not sure what im missing.

Here is my error log

```html
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844): Process: com.example.customview, PID: 29844
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.customview/com.example.customview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at com.example.customview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
11-05 20:43:58.552: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`, which means that `findViewById()` is sure to return null. The method should be something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.double_image);
    LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    ...
```